# AnyLogic - how to model boxes with products

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using AnyLogic to simulate a process. I find it hard to model the following. Imagine the arrival of boxes with products inside. The products (say pens) have different sizes. I have hundreds of these boxes in CSV files. I would like to bring them to the system as boxes, then I would like to split them within simulation based on their sizes.

Do I need to create these pens one by one and then use the 'batch' module to put them in boxes? Or can I easily read a csv with boxes where each box has a lot of pens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create Box agents with a parameter "numPens" (type integer). Create your boxes from the csv and fill the numPens value.

Later, when it comes to unboxing, you can use the "Split" object from the process library and split 1 box agents into `numPens` pen agents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if it is possible for the pens have different sizes? For example, if numPens = 5, but sizes are different (say 2 classes of sizes). Then I would like to split the same sized ones and but them in new boxes in an operation...

Comment: sure it is possible. Put in the right "if" statements and act accordingly. I suggest you try this first and then add more complexity. If you get stuck, you ask another question here on SOF (it is not a discussion board ;-) ). cheers